# Error converting data type varchar to datetime when running raw SQL but not when called by LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

A client is getting an error when running my code.  They sent me the SQL from profilder.

When I paste it into SQL Server Management Studio it fails with: **Error converting data type varchar to datetime**

However it doesn't fail when I run it on my local dev box or another clients production sever.

To test I created a simple app with a L2S datacontext containing one entity that looks something like:

```
public class UserAccount 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastActivity { get; set; }
}
```

Insert a record and then update it:

```
var account = db.UserAccounts.Single(a => a.Username == "Mojo");
account.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

The records gets updated in the database.  But when I grab the T-SQL from Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [UserAccount] SET [LastActivity] = @p2 WHERE ([Id] = @p0) AND ([Username] = @p1) AND ([LastActivity] IS NULL)',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4),@p2 datetime',@p0=1,@p1=N'Mojo',@p2='2009-11-10 14:04:41.7470000'
```

and execute it in SQL Server Management Studio I get: **Error converting data type varchar to datetime**

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the field type for LastActivity in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using identical connections in Management Studio as in your test app? It sounds like this isn't the case the connections have different regional settings, causing the date to be parsed differently.

Comment: All great answers, but this one was the closest.  The problem was solved by setting the "Connections" sections' "no count" property to on.  The docs say: "SET NOCOUNT ON eliminates the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the client for each statement in a stored procedure."  Not sure why this would do the trick though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the extra zeroes at the end of the date:

```
'2009-11-10 14:04:41.747' (works)
'2009-11-10 14:04:41.7470000' (error converting...)
```

The four extra zeroes are probably just visible in the Visual Studio debugger.  LINQ does not sent them to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of SQL Server perhaps?

The extra zeros in the date would make it a datetime2 type which would be acceptable in 2008 but not 2005.

Answer (score 1):

`DATETIME` should have only 3 digits after second, `DATETIME2` has 7 digits after second. Seems that the string is formatted for `DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once I was trying to Insert the date time as '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it may help somebody: in my case, the problem was that copying the query from SQL Profiler split the lines at the bottom where the parameters are, including several `varchar` parameters which contained timestamps. I believe this would fail both `datetime` and `datetime2`.

So, I had something like:

```
@p250=4, @p251=2, @p252=2, @p253=N'2021-03-23
15:20:00.123'
```